# Cant expand web.config in VS 2010 after "Apply Config Transforms"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 professional, when I create a new configuration -> staging -> Right-click web.config in web project -> Apply Config Transforms.

The files web.debug, web.release, and web.staging are created, but the web.config doesn't expand so you can edit those files, even if they are added to solution.

Why is this?

I'm running as administrator also.

Answer (score 0):

You should find that when you switch your configuration via the dropdown-list on the toolbar, when you open the web.config in solution explorer, the config for your current build configuration is the one that opens.